# How to link a section to navigation bar in bootstrap

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to link a specific section of one of my webpage to the navigation bar so that I can directly go to it from any other webpage.

What code should I use so that I can link it.

Help me out, please

Comment: @divyansh it only works when you are doing it on a single webpage but I am talking about multiple webpages.

For example, The section I want to link to my navigation bar is on the webpage "About" and lets say i am on webpage contact us, then this method does not work.

Comment: Hi, Mayur. I think using a anchor to an element would work for you, check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Linking_to_an_element_on_the_same_page You just need to generate the link the same way I did above.

Answer (score 2):

give an id to the div you are trying to link to as such :

```
<div id = "gohere"></div>
```

and edit the navbar links as follows:

```
<a href="#gohere">
```

This will scroll to the div , if you want to show the scroll animation too, use :

## optional

```
body{
scroll-behaviour:smooth
}
```